# How to get checkbox values and insert them to an observable array in knockouts

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Kategoriler </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:categories">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="tooltips" data-bind="value: name" data-bind="checked: categoriesToSend" />
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text:name"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my table that content checkboxex. I  want to get values from this checkboxes and insert this values to an observable array how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you would want to do something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: name }, checked: $parent.categoriesToSend" />
```

So, you want to:

- use a single `data-bind` attribute
- do a one-way binding for the `value` attribute using the `attr` binding
- use the `checked` binding against `categoriesToSend` which lives on the parent (not on the category itself), so it can be referenced using `$parent.categoriesToSend`

Here is a sample in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Vf5LA/